# BASH How to treat JSON inside a variable to remove only a specific part of the text

Tags: linux, bash

I have a big JSON inside a var and I need to remove only from that specific comma ( and I have incontable number of others comma before that ) until the penultimate Curly Brackets..
in short, Only the BOLD text..... ( text between ** and next ** )

edit

originally there is no ** in json, I put it in the code just to show where it starts and ends what I want to remove
##################################################

```
              }
        ]
    }**,
    "meta": {
        "timeout": 0,
        "priority": "LOW_PRIORITY",
        "validationType": "SAME_FINGERS",
        "labelFilters": [],
        "externalIDs": [
            {
                "name": "chaveProcesso",
                "key": "01025.2021.0002170"
            }
        ]
    }**
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you showed more context, but basically you want something like:

```
jq 'del(.meta)'
```

or:

```
jq 'with_entries(select(.key != "meta"))'
```

eg:

```
#!/bin/sh

json='{
    "foo": 5,
    "meta": {
        "timeout": 0,
        "priority": "LOW_PRIORITY",
        "validationType": "SAME_FINGERS",
        "labelFilters": [],
        "externalIDs": [
            {
                "name": "chaveProcesso",
                "key": "01025.2021.0002170"
            }
        ]
    }
}'

echo "$json" | jq 'del(.meta)'
```

Comment: You know `del(.meta)` does the same thing, right?

Comment: @oguzismail No, I'm still learning `jq`.  Thanks for that!

Comment: (should be able to remove the `. |` from the start as well).